# Compare file system properties/attributes of two files

Tags: windows-7, macos, ubuntu, filesystems, diff

There are many methods that can be used to compare the data of two files. That is not what I'm interested in here.

How can I easily compare or "perform a diff" of what could be called (perhaps you can also help figure out what to call this stuff) the "file-system/OS" properties/attributes of two files?

For example:

```
-Filename
-Permissions
-Timestamps (created/last modified/last accessed)
-Properties such as "Read Only" or "Hidden" "Executable"
-Any others not listed here that you know of
```

While I imagine there are different answers for each of them, can such a thing be done **(without too much pain)** in the following environments:

```
Windows 7     (assuming NTFS - does this matter?)
Ubuntu Linux  (assuming ext4 - does this matter?)
OSX           (assuming HFS+ - does this matter?)
```

If an answer contains a response relevant to only one of these environments I will still value it.

Comment: stat (*nix/os x) and dir/attrib/icacls (windows) are most likely what you're after. The details about the files you're looking for are called metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux/osx you can do the following

```
% stat foo > /tmp/foo.stat && stat bar > /tmp/bar.stat && diff /tmp/bar.stat /tmp/foo.stat
```

Should be pretty easy to wrap the above in a shell script.  There are likely ways to do this without using the tmp files.

Answer (score 2):

On *nix systems to compare info about `foo` and `bar` you can just:

```
diff <(stat foo) <(stat bar)
```

you can of course get more info with other commands:

```
diff <(ls -l foo ; stat foo) <(ls -l bar ; stat bar)
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine.  Use it instead.

Answer (score 1):

I hope [this](http://www.altap.cz/salamander/features/compare-directories/) is what you are looking for.. Its a 3rd party tool...